# Slideshow goes vertical instead of horizontal

Tags: slideshow

I made a slideshow for http://www.nails2you.nl/ but the slides goes vertical instead of horizontal and I don't know why.

I tried to float the list items but then the slideshow wont work at all.

How can I make my slideshow slide horizontal?

http://jsfiddle.net/8XfQR/  `<div id="sections">`

Comment: What software did you use to make this slideshow?

Comment: Could you please copy+paste your code that makes the slideshow?

Comment: I hope this JSFiddle will help http://jsfiddle.net/8XfQR/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try to manipulate the axis attribute in your init.js as it possibly changes the direction to slide to.